# How to convert a decision table to a consistent decision tree?

Tags: decision-tree

I am working from presentation from school, but I am not able to understand how they go from one step to the other. This is the decision table that I have.

[image]

From it, the first thing we have to do is to choose the root node among these nodes:

[image]

But I do not understand why for example from Q1 the Y branch has a1, a2 and the N branch has a1,a3.

This is then the final solution for the tree:

[image]

I am not sure if this is the correct name in English, maybe that's the reason I wasn't able to find any literature online.

I would appreciate an explanation or at least a link to a guide on how to convert decision tables to optimal decision trees that are consistent with the decision table.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on here, but perhaps somebody else does.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar001/dmbook/ch4.pdf